# Spring config files and specifying schema versions

Tags: spring

Seems you can not specify the version numbers in the spring config files:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

So is Spring going to the latest version in the classpath?  Where is this in spring docs if listed at all?

Answer (score 4):

There is a spring.schemas file in spring-beans.jar. This file contains pointers to the 
XSD files. Here is the value in the spring.schemas file.

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
```

Therefore, the file is in the package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml of the jar.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can specify the version:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/

Click the link, it lists all the available versioned XSDs.

However, the unversioned XSD always points to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

> So is Spring going to the latest version in the classpath?

Essentially, yes. This permits your config files to be ostensibly version-agnostic, mainly for reasons of forwards compatibility.

> Where is this in spring docs if listed at all?

I don't think it is.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I wanted to ask a quick question... Assuming you're using non-versioned xsd's, but versioned dependencies in your pom, will it still grab the newest version xsd regardless of the jar used to build the project?